# Why do I get stuck in this While loop?

Tags: ruby, while-loop, logical-operators

**While loop in Ruby**
I think the problem is pretty simple but I don't really understand it. When I answer the correct option, so it can be 'Even' or 'Uneven', it repeatedly ask me the question. It think the problem is with the `or` operator

```
puts 'Which numbers do you want to see, the even or uneven ones?'
answer = gets.chomp
    
 while answer != 'Uneven' or answer != 'Even'
   puts 'Please answer Even or Uneven.'
   answer = gets.chomp
 end
```

Is there a way to write a `while` loop with 2 options like here?

Comment: It's curious you didn't ask, `'Which numbers do you want to see, the even or odd ones?'

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was a word for "Uneven" numbers. English isn't my first language, but guess you learn something new everyday! :)

Comment: That was my assumption... I can't resist the urge to help others expand their knowledge of English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the conditions should be connected by **`and` instead of `or`**.

```
puts 'Which numbers do you want to see, the even or uneven ones?'
answer = gets.chomp

while answer != 'Even' and answer != 'Uneven'
  puts 'Please answer Even or Uneven.'
  answer = gets.chomp
end
```

Secondly, the code can be improved further:
Do not repeat yourself: move `gets.chomp` inside the loop.
Add [`downcase`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/downcase), so that the user can enter the string in  a case-insensitive way, e.g., `odd`, `Odd`, etc.
Make an infinite loop using `loop do ... end` and use `break` with an `if` to exit the loop more easily.
The loop creates a separate scope, so we need to make `cur_answer` visible in the outer scope. For this, make the loop return the `cur_answer` by using `break cur_answer` ([`break`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-break) with an argument returns that argument).
Replace the repetitive `!=` operators using an array of desired values and [`include?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F). The array of strings can be easily created using [`Percent Strings`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings), here `%w[...]`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts 'Which numbers do you want to see, even or odd ones?'

answer = loop do
  cur_answer = gets.chomp.downcase
  break cur_answer if %w[ even odd ].include? cur_answer
  puts 'Please answer even or odd.'
end

puts "answer=#{answer};"
```

Comment: I'd probably downcase the answer for a case-insensitive comparison, too...

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for your comments and many helpful suggestions to improve the code, especially for the use of `break` with an argument to return a value from the loop! I updated the answer.

Comment: @nullTerminator Thank you for the suggestion to make the comparison case-insensitive. I updated the answer.